# Draw 9-patch android

Tags: android, изображения

Добрый день, кто то может мне объяснить, как работает утилита Draw 9-patch?
Есть картинка http://hkar.ru/kiXA , собственно как сделать, что бы она растягивалась только по ширине, при этом нужно что бы значки по бокам не тянулись по ширине.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Черная линия слева и сверху обозначает то как будет тянуться картинка, снизу и справа область контекста.
Области которые не должны тянуться (в вашем случае значки) оставляете без черной линии.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте [этот](http://weblookandfeel.com/downloads/ninepatch-demo.jar) редактор, удобный, имеет превью